# Event becomes null in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, xamarin.ios

Hi Monotouch users,
I have this strange situation where I have a custom event declared in a custom UIView like so:

```
public delegate void SelectionChangedHandler(SelectableView selectedView, bool selected);
public event SelectionChangedHandler SelectionChanged;
```

I then assign to this handler in the initialize method of a viewcontroller like so:

```
SelectableView s;
...
SelectableView.SelectionChanged += HandleSelectionChanged;
```

I have checked and ensured that all the necessary objects still exist in memory and have not been garbage collected.

I am finding that the event becomes null sometime between the assignment and the drawing.
Has anybody come across this issue before? Or am I doing something obviously wrong in my use of events in MonoTouch?

**EDIT:**
Some additional information - the UIView is loaded from a xib file. I just tried with a UIView not loaded from a xib and everything works fine :| I am a little dumbfounded.

**EDIT 2:**
Even more information: All the properties set on the UIView loaded from the xib appear to become null as well!
Here is the code I use to load the UIView from the xib:

```
var v = new SelectableView(NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("SelectableView", this, null).ValueAt(0));
```

I then set a property on v:

```
v.SomeProperty = s;
```

By render time SomeProperty is null.

Cheers
Naren

Comment: Are you setting/accessing the property from different threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a lot of issues trying to use Interface Builder created UIViews. I found two workarounds: 1) Use a UIViewController instead, which uses up quite a bit more memory, or 2) Create the UIView in code (no xib file), which is somewhat less comfortable than using IB.

I end up going with the first option most of the time - just be aware of the number of currently-loaded viewcontrollers.

Comment: Yeah. That is what I have ended up doing. Thanks for the confirmation :)